# Tweets with photos not showing up in Twitter API search results

Tags: api, twitter

A previously working desktop app has stopped working recently. The problem is that tweets with photos aren't showing up in the api. I can verify this using the test console. Tweets with no image are returned. Tweets with images don't. I have tried posting both via a mobile device and the browser.
What's odd is they show up when searching by user:
1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
but not when searching by query:
/1.1/search/tweets.json

Has anyone has a similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Im has a similar experience. 1.1/search/tweets.json  all time back response without tweet with images.
I try implement post tweet with image  in different ways, but results was equal. Seem like search API  not fit for mobile OS.
Check it    ["Why am I missing from search?'](https://support.twitter.com/articles/66018)